# How to output data in angularJS where data is equal to now?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

So in my database, I have timestamps like `2016-12-30 00:30:10` and so on.. and I'm getting it via `$http` module. In my angular code I have this:

```
    angular
        .module('sampleApp')
        .controller('ReportCtrl', ReportCtrl)
        .factory('Reports', Reports)
        .filter('dateToISO', dateToISO);

    function ReportCtrl($scope, Reports) {
        $scope.returns = [];
        $scope.loadReturns = function () {
            Reports.getReturns().then(function (response) {
                $scope.returns = response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }

function dateToISO() {
        return function (input) {
            input = new Date(input).toISOString();
            return input;
        };
    }
```

and in the html:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="r in returns | orderBy:'-phdate'">
            <td ng-bind="r.product_name"></td>
            <td ng-bind="r.quantity"></td>
            <td ng-bind="r.username"></td>
            <td ng-bind="r.phdate | dateToISO | date:'medium'"></td>
        </tr>
```

So the output looks like this:

[image]

Now what I wanted to do, is to output only those dates who is equal to the current date. For example, today is `12/30/2016` and I want only data with that dates.

Should I do it server-side or can I do it in angular? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can do it from both side but if data is more then do it from server side for better performance.

Comment: When doing `new Date('2016-12-30 00:30:10')` the string will be treated as local (if parsed correctly, it may not be), so will represent a different moment in time for each host with a different timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using angular

**Html**

```
    <tr ng-repeat="r in returns | orderBy:'-phdate'">
        <td ng-bind="r.product_name"></td>
        <td ng-bind="r.quantity"></td>
        <td ng-bind="r.username"></td>
        <td ng-bind="compareDate(r.phdate)"></td>
    </tr>
```

**Js**

```
    var compareDate = function (phdate) {
         // Init time to zero
         var curDate = new Date();
         curDate.setHours(0);
         curDate.setMinutes(0);
         curDate.setSeconds(0);

         var pDate = new Date(phdate);
         pDate.setHours(0);
         pDate.setMinutes(0);
         pDate.setSeconds(0);

         if (curDate === pDate) {
             return $filter('date')(pDate, 'medium');
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.compareDate = function(phdate){
        var dateObj = new Date();
        var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
        var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
        var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
        var currentDate = day+ "" + month + "" + year;

        var dateOb = new Date(phdate);
        var monthData = dateOb.getUTCMonth() + 1;
        var dayData = dateOb.getUTCDate();
        var yearData = dateOb.getUTCFullYear();
        var dataDate = dayData + "" + monthData + "" + yearData;

        if(currentDate == dataDate){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }



<tr ng-repeat="r in returns | orderBy:'-phdate'" ng-if="compareDate(r.phdate)">
    <td ng-bind="r.product_name"></td>
    <td ng-bind="r.quantity"></td>
    <td ng-bind="r.username"></td>
    <td ng-bind="r.phdate"></td>
</tr>
```